# simple jquery length return bad value

Tags: jquery

it making me crazy, i'm probably stupid :)

Go to this link : http://www.willbegood.com/lab/whatup/list2.php?categ=4

Why to this page return "1", it should be return "4".
There are 4 div whith the id equal to "liste-item", why it return only 1?
My page is generated by a simple php query, is this the reason?

I have also tryed to test this with the same page but static (html) : same problem
Check here : http://www.willbegood.com/lab/whatup/list3.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot duplicate ID. ID should be unique in a DOM and the jQuery selector would return only 1 which is the first element with `liste-item`.

Use class instead of ID.

Answer (score 1):

You are only allowed one `id` element. That's probably why. Change it to `class`.

Answer (score 1):

**ID's** in a `HTML` page should be unique.

If you select it by **ID** , it will return the first occurrence of the **ID.**  It will not look further.

In such cases better to replace it with a `class.`

Replace `id="liste-item"`   **with**   `class="liste-item"`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are using id's where you need to be using class. Id's by definition need to be unique. When you select by Id in jquery (or straight JS) you will only get a single element. Change your div's to

```
<div class='liste-item off'></div>
<div class='liste-item off'></div>
<div class='liste-item off'></div>
<div class='liste-item off'></div>
```

And you JS to `alert($(".liste-item").length)`
A tutorial on id and class selectors can be found here: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssintermediate/classid/